# Use named pipes (or something else) as in-memory files

Tags: windows, winapi, file, pipe

I've been going through the WinAPI documentation for a while, but I don't seem to be able to find an answer.  What I'm trying to achieve is to give a program a file name that it can open and work with it like that would be a normal file on the disk.  But I want this object to be in the memory.

I tried using named pipes and they work in some of the situations, but not always.  I create a named pipe and pass it to the child process as a regular file.  When process exists I collect the data from the pipe.

```
program.exe \\.\pipe\input_pipe
```

Faced some limitations though.  One of them is that they are not seekable.  The second limitation is that they should be opened with exactly the right permissions.  And the third one I found is that you cannot pre-put any data into a duplex pipe before it's been open on the other end.  Is there any way to overcome those limitations of the named pipes?

Or maybe there is some other kind of object that could be opened with `CreateFile` and then accessed with `ReadFile` and `WriteFile`.  So far the only solution I see is to create a file system driver and implement all the functionality myself.

Just to make it clear I wanted to point out that I cannot change the child program I'm running.  The main idea is to give that program something that it would think is a normal file.

UPDATE: I'm not looking for a solution that involves installation of any external software.

Comment: Why do you want it to be in memory?

Comment: @Len: Two reasons. I don't want anybody to be able to see this file and for performance reasons.

Comment: The perf reason is bogus.  On Windows, when you allocate memory then you allocate disk.  The paging file.  You never write to the disk, you write to RAM.  And if it is read fast enough, it is read from RAM as well.  The file system cache.  About one gigabyte on most 32-bit machines, lots more on 64-bit machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>[Memory-mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366556%28VS.85%29.aspx) would allow you to do what you want.</strike>

EDIT:

On rereading the question - since the receiving program already uses `CreateFile/ReadFile/WriteFile` and cannot be modified, this will not work. I cannot think of a way to do what OP wants outside of third-party or self-written RAMDisk solution.

Comment: I tried this one two.  Either I did something wrong or it's not capable of doing what I need to do.  Is there a way to create a named file mapping object and then use `CreateFile` or `fopen` on it?

Comment: If you can't fopen it, you should be able to DuplicateHandle the mapping handle into the remote process.

Comment: @Chris: The only thing I can pass to the child process is a file name which will be fed to `fopen` or `CreateFile`.

Comment: Isn't a memory-mapped file more about giving the program a different interface for reading/writing the data than anything else? If you want to use ReadFile/WriteFile ideally then a memory-mapped file takes you away form the goal, not towards it. (Meanwhile, you can get the same sort of "keep it in memory and don't hit the disk" caching by using CreateFile normally with some different flags.)

Comment: @Leo - the idea would be that the receiving program uses the filename to map the file into memory.  I agree that (on rereading the q) since the receiving program already uses `CreateFile/ReadFile/WriteFile` and cannot be modified, this will not work.  I cannot think of a way to do what OP wants outside of third-party or self-written RAMDisk solution.

Comment: You just proved my concerns, I think I'd have to go with some sort of a RAM disk approach.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution might be, as you seem to suggest, using [a Ramdisk](https://superuser.com/questions/34388/whats-the-best-ramdisk-for-windows) to make a virtual drive mapped to memory.  Then obviously, any files you write to or read from that virtual drive will be completely contained in RAM (assuming it doesn't get paged to disk).

I've done that a few times myself to speed up a process that was entirely disk-bound.

Comment: I thought of that but I don't want my program to be dependent on any other software and make users install it.  Worst case I can do it myself using Dokan library, but that still would require a driver installation.

Comment: @detunized: You should update your question to reflect that.  I'm leaving the answer up for anyone else who comes across your question while in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Call CreateFile but with FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY and probably FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE as well.

The file will then never hit the disk unless the system is low on physical memory.

Comment: Thanks, I know this, but that's not what I need.

Comment: What is it that's unsuitable? You seem to want a file-like object that exists only in memory and, preferably, can be accessed via CreateFile/ReadFile/WriteFile. You can do all of those things with an actual file. :) What's the extra requirement here?

Comment: It's not really in memory.  When the child process crashes the files go to the disk.  I tried.

Comment: Even with delete-on-close? I know there are some weird semantics with that flag and multiple handles so you might be right... I'm not sure you will find a solution that meets all your constraints but good luck!